# Imports not found when running script outside of Pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have a project structured this way...

main.py imports scripts from subfolders like so:

```
from controllers.available_balances_controller import available_balances_controller
```

Subfolders:

- models
- views
- controllers

When running main.py in Pycharm it works find.

When I try to run in terminal I get import errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from controllers.available_balances_controller import available_balances_controller
ImportError: No module named controllers.available_balances_controller
```

Am I importing the scripts wrong in main.py?

What is the proper way to do the importing?

Comment: Any chance your terminal is using a different Python than what you configured for PyCharm? Or, perhaps you are not running the terminal Python from the project directory?

Comment: I'm using python3 terminal command + script name in the project directory.  Pycharm is configured for 3.5.  When I added blank __init__.py to all the folders it found the project modules.  But now it's not finding the site packages I imported in Pycharms interpreter.  Is there someplace I need to specify these in __init__.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running your script with the -m flag:

```
$ python -m main
```

That means that you are running your `main.py` as a *module* inside a python *package*, not as a simple *script*. PyCharm makes it easy for you by assuming so when you create a project. When you are in the terminal, you need to specify it yourself. You don't need `__init__.py` files inside your directories in Python3.

Check out:

- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html
- [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)