# Python script stops working when run outside of pycharm

Tags: python, python-module, pytube

I wrote my first program with a non built-in module and it works when I run it in pycharm, but when I try to run it in cmd I get an error: `app.py, line 1, in <module> from pytube import YouTube ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'`
I've tried installing pytube module via cmd once again, but the problem still occurs

EDIT: The rest of my scripts are working fine (there are using built-in only modules)

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! did you run `pip install pytube`, and did you make sure your pip corresponded to the correct version of Python you were running.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and I use both the newest version of python 3 and pip, so it should be correct

Comment: you can have a new pip but it might be pointing to the wrong python interpreter

Comment: How to check if that's the case?

Comment: try using `python -m pip install pytube` or whichever command for `python` that you use (i.e. `python3`)

Comment: after using the command you wrote above I get a return: Requirement already satisfied: (path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some research and trying different solutions, I managed to run my script just by copying the missing module to the same directory as my app.py file, I don't know if it's the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing Pytube with pip on your command prompt? Enter: `pip3 install pytube` in your terminal and rerun the script. It wasn't clear with the original post if you already did this.

If this doesn't work, try running your script with the -m flag: `$ python -m main`

A more detailed answer for this issue is already available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36925238/7732596).

Comment: Yes, I installed pytube with pip command, and unfortunately running script with -m doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Can you provide any other information? What was the result of the pip command; what was the command you entered with -m; what was the error given when running the script with -m?

Comment: I've run a command: (rest of the path)\app.py python -m main, and I got a return: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'

Comment: Could you try (rest of the path)\python -m app

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution above doesn't work (I get the same error). 
PS: For now I am looking for a solution better than mine because for now, it's the only one that's working, but I have to wait 2 days until I can mark my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an environment when you were in pyCharm? There's a chance you have to activate the env when you are in the cmd prompt.

Console without an environment

```
C:\path>
```

Activate environment named 'base'

```
C:\path>activate base
```

Console with an environment named 'base'

```
(base) C:\path>
```

Comment: No, I haven't done that, but when I try to run a command to activate environment cmd does not recognize it

Comment: How did you install pytube when your code did work?

Comment: My code worked fine from the beginning, but only in pycharm, It never worked in cmd tho. I just ran pip install pytube